# apache2 django 1.8 wsgy.py can not find my project

Tags: django, apache, wsgi, python-3.5, django-1.8

I am facing a problem for 2 days making running my project into production.
My project is called 'rfaapp' and when i try to access a page there is this apache error : Importerror no module named rfaapp.

this my apache 2 000-default.conf

'

```
 <VirtualHost *:80>
        # The ServerName directive sets the request scheme, hostname and port that
        # the server uses to identify itself. This is used when creating
        # redirection URLs. In the context of virtual hosts, the ServerName
        # specifies what hostname must appear in the request's Host: header to
        # match this virtual host. For the default virtual host (this file) this
        # value is not decisive as it is used as a last resort host regardless.
        # However, you must set it for any further virtual host explicitly.
        #ServerName www.example.com

        ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
        DocumentRoot /var/www/html

        # Available loglevels: trace8, ..., trace1, debug, info, notice, warn,
        # error, crit, alert, emerg.
        # It is also possible to configure the loglevel for particular
        # modules, e.g.
        #LogLevel info ssl:warn

        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

        # For most configuration files from conf-available/, which are
        # enabled or disabled at a global level, it is possible to
        # include a line for only one particular virtual host. For example the
        # following line enables the CGI configuration for this host only
        # after it has been globally disabled with "a2disconf".
        #Include conf-available/serve-cgi-bin.conf
        Alias /static /home/adminrfaapp/rfaapp/static
        <Directory /home/adminrfaapp/rfaapp/static>
                Require all granted
        </Directory>

        <Directory /home/adminrfaapp/rfaapp/rfaapp>
                <Files wsgi.py>
                        Require all granted
                </Files>
        </Directory>
        #WSGIDaemonProcess rfa python-path=/home/adminrfaapp/.local/lib/python3.5

        WSGIDaemonProcess rfaapp python-path=/home/adminrfaapp/rfaapp/rfaapp:/home/adminrfaapp/.local/lib/python3.5
        WSGIProcessGroup rfaapp
        WSGIScriptAlias / /home/adminrfaapp/rfaapp/rfaapp/wsgi.py

</VirtualHost>
```

'

my wsgi.py

```
`
import os
import sys

from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application
sys.path.append('home/adminrfaapp/rfaapp')
os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "rfaapp.settings")

application = get_wsgi_application()
`
```

anyone has a idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some ideas:

1/ Make sure you have the __init__.py file in the rfaapp folder.

2/ In your wsgi.py file you are forgetting the prepending / in your home path.

3/ In your wsgi.py file, instead of appending your rfaapp path, you may be wanting to put it in the first position:

```
sys.path.insert(1, '/home/adminrfaapp/rfaapp')
```

Comment: Thanks reply. i made this change and this solve my problem! thanks you so much!